# IoC (Ninject) and Factories

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, ninject, ioc-container

If I have the following code:

```
public class RobotNavigationService : IRobotNavigationService {
  public RobotNavigationService(IRobotFactory robotFactory) {
    //...
  }
}
public class RobotFactory : IRobotFactory {
  public IRobot Create(string nameOfRobot) {
    if (name == "Maximilian") {
      return new KillerRobot(); 
    } else {
      return new StandardRobot();
    }
  }
}
```

My question is what is the proper way to do Inversion of Control here? I don't want to add the KillerRobot and StandardRobot concretes to the Factory class do I? And I don't want to bring them in via a IoC.Get<> right? bc that would be Service Location not true IoC right? Is there a better way to approach the problem of **switching the concrete at runtime**?

Comment: Might want to check your code - the very first line is not legal C#.

Comment: Sorry. Thanks for the reminder. Thought I fixed that before posting. Correcting now.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For your sample, you have a perfectly fine factory implementation and I wouldn't change anything.

However, I suspect that your KillerRobot and StandardRobot classes actually have dependencies of their own.   I agree that you don't want to expose your IoC container to the RobotFactory.

One option is to use the ninject factory extension:

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki

It gives you two ways to inject factories - by interface, and by injecting a Func which returns an IRobot (or whatever).

Sample for interface based factory creation: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki/Factory-interface

Sample for func based: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki/Func

If you wanted, you could also do it by binding a func in your IoC Initialization code.  Something like:

```
var factoryMethod = new Func<string, IRobot>(nameOfRobot =>
                        {
                            if (nameOfRobot == "Maximilian")
                            {
                                return _ninjectKernel.Get<KillerRobot>();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return _ninjectKernel.Get<StandardRobot>();
                            }

                        });
_ninjectKernel.Bind<Func<string, IRobot>>().ToConstant(factoryMethod);
```

Your navigation service could then look like:

```
    public class RobotNavigationService
    {
        public RobotNavigationService(Func<string, IRobot> robotFactory)
        {
            var killer = robotFactory("Maximilian");
            var standard = robotFactory("");
        }
    }
```

Of course, the problem with this approach is that you're writing factory methods right inside your IoC Initialization -  perhaps not the best tradeoff...

The factory extension attempts to solve this by giving you several convention-based approaches - thus allowing you to retain normal DI chaining with the addition of context-sensitive dependencies.

Comment: Going to try out the extension - you sold me! +1 & answer

Comment: @BuddyJoe ever get the code running using the Factory method above?

Comment: I did. And If I remember the final code was very near to this.

Answer (score 4):

The way you should do:

```
kernel.Bind<IRobot>().To<KillingRobot>("maximilliam");
kernel.Bind<IRobot>().To<StandardRobot>("standard");
kernel.Bind<IRobotFactory>().ToFactory();

public interface IRobotFactory
{
    IRobot Create(string name);
}
```

But this way I think you lose the null name, so when calling `IRobotFactory.Create` you must ensure the correct name is sent via parameter.

When using `ToFactory()` in interface binding, all it does is create a proxy using Castle (or dynamic proxy) that receives an IResolutionRoot and calls the Get().

Comment: Yea I like to do it this way +1

Answer (score 3):

> ***I don't want to add the KillerRobot and StandardRobot concretes to the Factory class do I?***

I would suggest that you probably do. What would the purpose of a factory be if not to instantiate concrete objects? I think I can see where you're coming from - if `IRobot` describes a contract, shouldn't the injection container be responsible for creating it? Isn't that what containers are for?

Perhaps. However, returning concrete factories responsible for `new`ing objects seems to be a pretty standard pattern in the IoC world. I don't think it's against the principle to have a concrete factory doing some actual work.

Comment: Although not illustrated by his sample code, I think the problem he has is that KillerRobot and StandardRobot actually have further dependencies which need to be resolved by ninject as well.

Comment: And then how would you handle lets say if KillerRobot and Standard Robot had dependencies?

Comment: If you use either the interface or func based approaches in the factory extension, recursive dependency resolution will take place.

Comment: Question: kernel.Bind<IBarFactory>().ToFactory(); - Does this mean it will always just clip the I from the front of the interface name and then go lucking for the concrete in the same assembly? or are there more options then this?

Comment: It's more sophisticated.  The ToFactory() will actually look at your interface via reflection and generate a dynamic 'proxy' factory.  for example if you have:

public interface IBarFactory
{
    Bar CreateBar(int x, int y);
}

Your bar constructor could actually look like:

Bar(object Dependency1, object Dependency2, int x, int y).

Comment: ahhh. ok. I'm starting to follow you.

Comment: Also, see my edit.  Perhaps seeing how the pattern can be done "manually" will give you a better idea of what the factory extension is doing on your behalf behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to clean up a massive switch statement that returned a C# class to do some work (code smell here).

I didn't want to explicitly map each interface to its concrete implementation in the ninject module (essentially a mimic of lengthy switch case, but in a diff file) so I setup the module to bind all the interfaces automatically:

```
public class FactoryModule: NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly()
                            .IncludingNonPublicTypes()
                            .SelectAllClasses()
                            .InNamespaceOf<FactoryModule>()
                            .BindAllInterfaces()
                            .Configure(b => b.InSingletonScope()));
    }
}
```

Then create the factory class, implementing the StandardKernal which will Get the specified interfaces and their implementations via a singleton instance using an IKernal:

```
    public class CarFactoryKernel : StandardKernel, ICarFactoryKernel{
    public static readonly ICarFactoryKernel _instance = new CarFactoryKernel();

    public static ICarFactoryKernel Instance { get => _instance; }

    private CarFactoryKernel()
    {
        var carFactoryModeule = new List<INinjectModule> { new FactoryModule() };

        Load(carFactoryModeule);
    }

    public ICar GetCarFromFactory(string name)
    {
        var cars = this.GetAll<ICar>();
        foreach (var car in cars)
        {
            if (car.CarModel == name)
            {
                return car;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public interface ICarFactoryKernel : IKernel
{
    ICar GetCarFromFactory(string name);
}
```

Then your StandardKernel implementation can get at any interface by the identifier of you choice on the interface decorating your class.

e.g.:

```
    public interface ICar
{
    string CarModel { get; }
    string Drive { get; }
    string Reverse { get; }
}

public class Lamborghini : ICar
{
    private string _carmodel;
    public string CarModel { get => _carmodel; }
    public string Drive => "Drive the Lamborghini forward!";
    public string Reverse => "Drive the Lamborghini backward!";

    public Lamborghini()
    {
        _carmodel = "Lamborghini";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
        [Test]
    public void TestDependencyInjection()
    {
        var ferrari = CarFactoryKernel.Instance.GetCarFromFactory("Ferrari");
        Assert.That(ferrari, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(ferrari, Is.Not.Null.And.InstanceOf(typeof(Ferrari)));

        Assert.AreEqual("Drive the Ferrari forward!", ferrari.Drive);
        Assert.AreEqual("Drive the Ferrari backward!", ferrari.Reverse);

        var lambo = CarFactoryKernel.Instance.GetCarFromFactory("Lamborghini");
        Assert.That(lambo, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(lambo, Is.Not.Null.And.InstanceOf(typeof(Lamborghini)));

        Assert.AreEqual("Drive the Lamborghini forward!", lambo.Drive);
        Assert.AreEqual("Drive the Lamborghini backward!", lambo.Reverse);
    }
```