# Ninject Contextual Binding at runtime depending on a specific value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject.web.mvc

My scenario is the following:

I have an interface `IVendor`. I have three different classes implementing this, lets call them `Vendor1`, `Vendor2`, `Vendor3`.

I have a web api call that will give me availability of the vendor's products. Of course each vendor has its own check availability procedures, hence the interface that exposes a `CheckAvailability` method.

So in my call i have something like:

```
public bool Get(int productId)
{
    var product = GetProductByID(productId);
    switch(product.VendorId)
    {
        case 1:
            return Vendor1(CheckAvailability(product.VendorProductCode));
            break;
        case 2:
            return Vendor2(CheckAvailability(product.VendorProductCode));
            break;
        case 3:
            return Vendor3(CheckAvailability(product.VendorProductCode));
            break;
        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }
}
```

This is very simplistic and of course i do not like it. I would like to be able to call something like

```
public bool Get(int productId)
{
    var product = GetProductByID(productId);
    return IVendor.CheckAvailability(product.VendorProductCode)
}
```

and IVendor to be injected to whatever is needed through Ninject. Am i asking something crazy? Is that even possible?

Comment: You need to use a factory that will implement this logic. Unfortunately we are not at a level yet that this can be done conceptually. However the factory option will be executed at a lower level and provide the right implementation.

Comment: Is it possible to give an example?

Comment: I could later on tonight.. at work at the moment

Comment: Thanks anyway. I will have a research on factory as well.

Comment: have a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285946/ioc-ninject-and-factories

Comment: These commends were indeed very helpful and seem to set me on the right track. I have not yet test this. But when i do, and if you have an answer i will accept it.